# Using the value for a function in another function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a mastermind game and I've just started and hit a stumbling block. I need to allow the user to choose the number of pegs in the game and then allow the user to guess the code. I am trying to check the length of the guess and make sure it's the same as the number of pegs that they chose. Here is my code so far:

```
def pegs():
    numberOfPegs = input("Please enter the number of pegs in the game between 3 and 8 ")
    if numberOfPegs < 3:
        return ("Make sure you enter a number between 3 and 8")
    elif numberOfPegs > 8:
        return ("Make sure you enter a number between 3 and 8")
    else:
        return ("Thank you, you are playing with", numberOfPegs, "pegs")



def checker():

    guess = raw_input("Please enter your guess as letters ")
    if len(guess) != pegs:
        print "Wrong number!"
    else:
        return 1

print pegs()
print "\n"
print checker()
```

And the checker() always returns "Wrong number" even when the amount of letters in the guess I input is the same as the number of pegs i've chosen and I can't figure out why.

Thanks!

Comment: you should return a number from first function, and pass it to second function. `pegs` is not having any value here.

Comment: @Janith Chinthana Sorry, but how do I do that? I tried adding `return numberOfPegs` and using that in the `checker()` function but that doesn't work as `numberOfPegs` only exists in the `pegs` function.

Comment: instead of return `("Thank you, you are playing with", numberOfPegs, "pegs")` , return `numberOfPegs` only. And If you need to print something use `print` inside the function.

Comment: if you return a number use `if len(guess) != pegs():` code.

Comment: I'm returning numberOfPegs now, but when running i'm getting an error due to `if len(guess) != numberOfPegs:` saying that numberOfPegs is not defined.

Comment: I suspect that you do not actually understand the difference between `print` and `return`, and would be better served by actually studying this first before trying to ask the question.

Comment: I think a bigger issue is the issue of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return line in your pegs() should return the number of pegs so that you can save that value and use it again from the top level of your program:

```
def pegs():
    ...
    return numberOfPegs
```

Have the function print what you want before returning. Then, in your main program:

```
npegs = pegs()
checker(npegs)   # send the number of pegs to the checker function
```

And define checker appropriately:

```
def checker(pegs):
    ...
```

Edit to add: Check out this [explanation of scope](https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-17/python-scope-basics) in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_pegs():
    numberOfPegs = input("Please enter the number of pegs in the game between 3 and 8 ")
    if numberOfPegs < 3:
        print ("Make sure you enter a number between 3 and 8");
        return 0;
    elif numberOfPegs > 8:
        print ("Make sure you enter a number between 3 and 8");
        return 0;
    else:
        print ("Thank you, you are playing with ", numberOfPegs, " pegs");
        return numberOfPegs;

def checker(pegs):

    guess = raw_input("Please enter your guess as letters ")
    if len(guess) != pegs:
        print "Wrong number!"
    else:
        print "Number ok";    #for debugging, remove later
        return 1

pegs =  get_pegs();
print "\n"
result = checker(pegs);
```